# How can I calculate phone's width and height in density pixels

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

For instance, I have a Galaxy Tab 2 http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_tab_2_10_1_p5100-4567.php which has display size 800 x 1280 pixels

How can I calculate with and height in dp?
I want to use relevant values in resource folder names

```
values-sw600dp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Galaxy Tab 2 has 10.1" display and 800 x 1280.

For sw (smallest width):

```
800 / (141/160) = 800 / 0.88125 = 907.8 dp -> so it fits to for example into sw600dp.

141 - DPI of screen
160 - DPI of MDPI screen
800 - pixels in width
```

Basicaly sw-600dp fits to 7" tablets and sw-720dp fits to 10" tablets.